# JAVASCRIPT --> Why do I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function "?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wonder why I get the error message (Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function) , this is my bit of Code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function dataparse(points)
   {
      points = points.substr(0, points.length - 1);
      var linar = points.split("\n");
      // Break each point by line break
      var wrkar = [];
      var pntar = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < linar.length; i++)
      {
          wrkar = linar[i].split(",", 2);
          // Break each point into x and y
          pntar.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(wrkar[0]), parseFloat(wrkar[1])));
      }
      return pntar;
  }


  var cd = [
  (30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539)
  (30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805)
  (30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422)
  (30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594)
  ];

  var df = dataparse(cd);
  alert('df');
```

Answer (score 4):

`(30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539)` evaluates to `-9.582610613708539`

Together with the next line, it's interpreted as

`-9.577975756530805(30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805)`

Which of course fails because `-9.577...` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `dataparse` function expects a string, given `points.substr(0,points.length - 1)`
2. you initialize cd as an array, but the parser tries to execute `(num1, num2) (num3, num4)` as a function (see GGG's answer for the reason).

Answer (score 0):

The error raises because of `cd` variable. You use parentheses, however it is not corrent.
Following your `dataparse` method `cd` variable should look like:

```
var cd = "30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539\n"+
    "30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805\n"+
    "30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422\n"+
    "30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594";
```

**UPDATE**: However, you can rewrite your code in the more nice form:

```
function dataparse(points) {
    var pntar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        pntar.push(new google.maps.LatLng(points[i][0], points[i][1]));
    }
    return pntar;
}

var cd = [
    [30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539],
    [30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805],
    [30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422],
    [30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594]
    ];

var df = dataparse(cd);
alert(df);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're points array isn't valid. You will have to use square brackets for the points itself and split them by commas

```
var cd = [
    [30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539],
    [30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805],
    [30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422],
    [30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594]
];
```

And with that you will also have to modify (simplify) your `dataparse` function to handle the array correctly

```
function dataparse(points) {
    var i,
        length,
        pntar = [];

    for (i = 0, length = points.length; i < length; i++) {
        pntar.push(new google.maps.LatLng(points[i][0], points[i][1]));
    }

    return pntar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this, because every number in your brackets is evaluated, you should replace that with the proper argument which your function accepts... since you are using `substr`, but actually you want to pass an array you should add some code to your function as well :

```
function dataparse(pairs)
{
    for ( i=0; i < pairs.length ; i++ ) {
       var wrkar = pairs[i].split(", ",2);
       var pntar = [] ;
       pntar.push( new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(wrkar[0]), parseFloat(wrkar[1])) ); 
       return pntar;
    }    
}


var cd = [
        "30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539",
        "30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805",
        "30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422",
        "30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594"
];

var df = dataparse(cd);
alert('df');​
```

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ptQfc/

Answer (score 0):

**1st misake:**

```
var cd = [
            (30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539)
(30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805)
(30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422)
(30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594)
];
```

Javascript array has to be separated with commas and not with newlines!

Comment: This would just give you an array of values like: "(number","number)(number","number)(number" and so on. Brackets have no place in array declaration in Javascript.

Comment: except if you are using tanary : `(point ? point : "30.4343")`

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the syntax required and it's causing a whole host of errors, namely trying to interpret your variables as a function.

In Javascript, the `var=[val,val2]` construct creates an array. You're trying to treat the contents of the brackets as a string, and split it as such.

A better way to store the array would be:

```
var cd = [
    [30.40545181622765, -9.582610613708539],
    [30.405229737948233, -9.577975756530805],
    [30.40300892737293, -9.577546603088422],
    [30.402268645956614, -9.584241396789594]
];
```

Your function could then be written as:

```
function dataparse(linar) {
    var wrkar = [] ;
    var pntar = [] ;
    for (var i = 0; i < linar.length; i++) {
        wrkar = linar[i];                // Break each point into x and y
        pntar.push( new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(wrkar[0]),parseFloat(wrkar[1]))); 
    }
    return pntar ;
}
```

as `linar` is an array of arrays, each time you loop through the array it sets the next array down as the value of `wrkar`, which gives you the `x` and `y` coordinates.